# Using python to call Emboss wordcount

Tags: python, emboss

Hi guys I would like to run wordcount from Emboss in a bunch of fasta files. I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess



filenames = ['Downloads/Data/GCF_000016725.1_chr.fna']
for filename in filenames:
    name = filename.split('/')[2]
    print(filename)
    subprocess.call (['wordcount', 'Input sequence(s): ' + filename, 'Word size [4]: ' + sys.argv[1]])
```

But I got error messages:

```
Count and extract unique words in molecular sequence(s)
Error: Failed to open filename 'Input sequence(s): Downloads/Data/GCF_000016725.1_chr.fna'
Error: Unable to read sequence 'Input sequence(s): Downloads/Data/GCF_000016725.1_chr.fna'
Died: wordcount terminated: Bad value for '-sequence' and no prompt
```

But if a use shell with Downloads/Data/GCF_000016725.1_chr.fna  it works fine!

Any tip would be helpful!
I am using python, but I would have a method to compare my results!

Thank you by your time!

Paulo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use command line options, not interactive prompts, like so:

```
subprocess.call(['wordcount', '-sequence', filename, '-wordsize', sys.argv[1]], '-outfile', filename + '.wordcount.txt')
```

Or, using the [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
subprocess.call(f'wordcount -sequence {filename} -wordsize {sys.argv[1]} -outfile {filename}.wordcount.txt')
```

Note that I had to add `-outfile` option to your system call, otherwise `wordcount` prompts for the output file. See [`wordcount` manual](https://www.bioinformatics.nl/cgi-bin/emboss/help/wordcount).

Comment: I tested your first solution and worked very nicelly. Thank you by your time and patience. Paulo